# How to include Sunday as part of This week in Conditional Formatting?

Tags: excel

[image: Spreadsheet Snapshot]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbIWw.png):

How do I include Sunday as part of This week's Conditional Formatting?

Today's date is Tue 16/08. On the attached image the dates Thu18/08-Sat20/08 are highlighted pink/red. However, Sun 21/08 is not included as part of the week.

I have seen formulas that would pick weekends, but that will pick ALL weekends. This is NOT the one I was after.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: something like `= WEEKNUM( A1 ) = WEEKNUM( NOW() )` if in the same year. [WEEKNUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKNUM-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `WEEKNUM` function and a formula based conditional formatting rule:

```
=(WEEKNUM(F1,2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2))
```

where `F1` is the top cell in the column you want to apply the formatting to and the second argument `2` of the `WEEKNUM` function designates that the week starts on a Monday rather than a Sunday.

If you have dates spanning multiple years, you will need to check that the years match as well:

```
=AND(WEEKNUM(F1,2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY(),2),YEAR(F1)=YEAR(TODAY()))
```